# Dictionary 'update' method

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a script that builds multiple dictionaries and consolidate them as a single dictionary to return to the calling entity. The requirement is to append each dictionary at the end of the previous one. While I was building it in my PC (Windows 10, python 3.x), it worked fine as below.

```
{
  "Array Name": "SU73ARWVSPF01",
  "storageSystemId": "22186",
  "storageSystemName": "POD5_SU73ARWVSPF01",
  "accessible": true,
  "model": "VSP G1500",
  "svpIpAddress": "10.185.35.37",
  "firmwareVersion": "80-06-78-00/00",
  "lastRefreshedTime": "2020-12-21 14:45:31",
  "Pool List": {
     "Pool-1": {
      "storagePoolId": 11,
      "label": "DATA",
      "capacityInBytes": 590323982008320,
      "usedCapacityInBytes": 422152148877312,
      "availableCapacityInBytes": 168171833131008,
      "usedSubscription": 83
    },
      "Pool-2": {
      "storagePoolId": 12,
      "label": "LOGS",
      "capacityInBytes": 28142827732992,
      "usedCapacityInBytes": 21991601995776,
      "availableCapacityInBytes": 6151225737216,
      "usedSubscription": 78
    }
  },
  "SNMP Manager List": {
    "SNMP-1": {
      "name": "Test",
      "ipAddress": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    "SNMP-2": {
      "name": "Test1",
      "ipAddress": "2.2.2.2"
    }
   },
  "Hardware Alert List": {
    "diskAlerts": false,
    "powerSupplyAlerts": false,
    "batteryAlerts": false,
    "fanAlerts": false,
    "portAlerts": false,
    "cacheAlerts": false,
    "memoryAlerts": false,
    "processorAlerts": false
  }
}
```

However, after moving it to the server where the actual program will run (RHEL 7, python 2.7), the order of the dictionary is getting messed up as below.

```
{
  "accessible": true,
  "storageSystemName": "POD5_SU73ARWVSPF01",
  "Hardware Alert List": {
    "cacheAlerts": false,
    "powerSupplyAlerts": false,
    "portAlerts": false,
    "processorAlerts": false,
    "batteryAlerts": false,
    "diskAlerts": false,
    "fanAlerts": false,
    "memoryAlerts": false
  },
  "SNMP Manager List": {
    "SNMP-1": {
      "ipAddress": "1.1.1.1",
      "name": "Test"
    },
    "SNMP-2": {
      "ipAddress": "2.2.2.2",
      "name": "Test1"
    }
  },
  "svpIpAddress": "10.185.35.37",
  "storageSystemId": "22186",
  "Array Name": "SU73ARWVSPF01",
  "lastRefreshedTime": "2020-12-21 21:45:31",
  "model": "VSP G1500",
  "Pool List": {
    "Pool-2": {
      "usedSubscription": 78,
      "label": "LOGS",
      "usedCapacityInBytes": 21991601995776,
      "storagePoolId": 12,
      "availableCapacityInBytes": 6151225737216,
      "capacityInBytes": 28142827732992
    },
    "Pool-1": {
      "usedSubscription": 83,
      "label": "DATA",
      "usedCapacityInBytes": 422152148877312,
      "storagePoolId": 11,
      "availableCapacityInBytes": 168171833131008,
      "capacityInBytes": 590323982008320
    }
  },
  "firmwareVersion": "80-06-78-00/00"
}
```

The output from the first one is how I wanted and programmed it, by using the

```
OUTPUT={}
OUTPUT.update(new Dict1), OUTPUT.update(new Dict2).... etc
```

Is there a way to avoid the dictionaries getting inserted in the middle of the other one rather than at the end of it

Comment: The order of dictionary elements shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you care about order you should be using lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionaries did preserve order of items added to them officially until version 3.7 — so that's like the reason why — but as @Barmar said, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @martineau They remember the order of insertion, it's not clear how that applies to merging with `.update()`.

Comment: @Barmar: When `updates` changes the value of something already in the `dict`, the order of those item doesn't change, if the item is new, then it's added at the current end. I think this may be in the documentation somewhere…

Comment: Right, and I guess the description of what they're trying to do implies that each input dictionary has distinct keys.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dictionaries maintaining their insertion order have only been a feature [since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict) (although they were only an implementation detail back then; alternative Python implementations didn't have to adhere to this). [Starting from Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html), this has become a language specification.

Because you are using Python 2.7 on your server, dictionary order is not guaranteed using the default `dict` class. You can use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class to ensure insertion order is remembered.